# the Gauss-Jordan algorithm requires how many multiplications/divisions and add/subtractions

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to show this following result.

The Gauss-Jordan algorithm requires $\frac{n^3}{2}+n^2-\frac{n}{2}$ multiplications/divisions and requires $\frac{n^3}{2}-\frac{n}{2}$ additions/subtractions. I'm not sure exactly how to start to show this. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about elimination to put an augmented $n\times  (n+1)$ matrix into reduced row echelon form, without pivoting?

Comment: hardmath, yes, that is correct. maybe I should have mentioned this- the matrix A and the constant matrix b are put together- the augmented matrix

Comment: actually, I think my book allows pivoting. That's what the multiplication/division and addition/subtraction would come from, no? Say I pivot on an entry and I multiply the other rows by some  number and then add/subtract to make those entries $0$ as per the algorithm

Comment: The clearing of a column using a "pivot" (creating a leading one at that location in the current row) is part of GJ elimination.  When we say "without pivoting" it means assume the first nonzero entry in the next row can be successfully used to reduced the matrix (so in this context, "pivoting" means having to search for the location of a "pivot" entry).